# Silverlight: ComboboxItem text not updated when binding changes

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, combobox

I have an issue whereby when I update the text on a Comboboxitem it isnt instantly reflected on the UI. One has to click the Combobox to show the items (which have the correct text).  Any ideas why? Note this exact code works perfectly in WPF

The property that defines the string to show

```
public string NormallyOpenString
{
    get
    {
        if (this.IsInput)
        {
            return "High";
        }
        else if (this.IsRelay)
        {
            return "Open";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Open (High)";
        }
    }
}
```

Which is bound to a Combobox like so

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Normally, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding NormallyOpenString}"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding NormallyClosedString}" />
</ComboBox>
```

When another combobox changes I want to update the text as it changes what `IsInput` / `IsRelay` is.  I do this via `NotifyPropertyChanged` like so

```
this.NotifyPropertyChanged("NormallyOpenString");
this.NotifyPropertyChanged("NormallyClosedOpenString");
this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Normally");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it that way, so I can't vouch for it.  This is how I do property change notification:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private string normallyOpenString = "I'm an open string!";
    public string NormallyOpenString
    {
        get { return normallyOpenString; }
        set
        {
            normallyOpenString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NormallyOpenString");
        }
    }        
}
```

So now, whenever anyone calls your setter, anything bound to your property will be updated.  So if it gets set from one binding, all other bindings that are also bound to it will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather use the SelectedItem property.